# 2 smart tables on 1 page, pagination changes both tables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, smart-table

I have 2 smart-tables on 1 page, each with pagination inside tfoot. The actual st-pagination is as simple as:

```
  <st-pagination st-items-by-page="15" st-displayed-pages="6"></st-pagination>
```

The problem is that when I change page on one of them, both tables change page.  Is there a way to essentially point each table to its own pagination so that changing page on one pagination would only change 1 table's page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a silly mistake - I need to bind different collections in st-table.
i.e.

table 1:

```
<table st-table="collection1" st-safe-src="srcTable">
```

table 2:

```
<table st-table="collection2" st-safe-src="srcTable">
```